# How to convert rest web service call returns xml into json in sencha

Tags: xml, json, extjs, local-storage

Webservice request returns XML. How do I convert this into JSON in sencha touch and then load the data into a list? How can I also choose which information could be stored in the local storage?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create model and store for that.

you can create model like this,

```
 Ext.regModel('Travel', {
  idProperty: 'Travelled',
   fields: [ { name: 'Month', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'Travel', type: 'int' },
         { name: 'Addition', type: 'int' },
         { name: 'Traveled', type: 'int' },
         { name: 'outcome', type: 'int' }]
   });
```

and stor like this

```
 Ext.regStore('TravelStore', {
model: 'Travel',
storeId: "TravelID"
});
```

and you need to pass the data into this store by using arrays with the help of Xml response.